# Is there a shortcut to invert colors using the magnifier in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I prefer to read documents with color inversion (my eyes don't like white backgrounds). But I found it annoying to click the magnifier and check/uncheck the option. Can I do this with a shortcut?

Comment: [Invert display colors](https://superuser.com/q/358316/241386)

Answer (score 14):

When Magnifier is turned on (it can be minimized), then Ctrl + Alt + I toggles color inversion. Quite handy.

Comment: it's unfortunate that Magnifier needs to be running for this keyboard shortcut to work.

Answer (score 4):

Yup.

It's `Left_Alt + Left_Shift + Print_Screen`.

Have fun.

*This command does not invert all colors, it turns on "*high contrast*" settings, which inverts the colors of some parts of the screen, but not at all, only the main text parts of Microsoft made applications.

Magnifier allows you to invert all colors on the screen like a mac does, but there is no shortcut for that when the Magnifier program is not open.

Comment: When the confirmation box shows up, you are given a link to the configuration page. Take it. There you can disable the confirmation dialog box for good.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a 1 key toggle to flip for viewing images do this:

1. Download [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) - free.
2. Alter the script file in the app to shortcut the windows shortcut to being the context menu button.
3. Put this code in the script file and put a white sticker over the button. Great for minor visual problems.:

   `AppsKey::Send ^!{i}`

Has saved big hassle fiddling for three keys. If you can spare a button go for it.

All it means is when I press the <kbd>Appskey</kbd>, to virtually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. Look at documentation to change the key you assign.

Answer (score 0):

Update. Windows7. you can pin it to the task bar and minimize it so it does not have an open window and than shift+alt+I works just like Mac. It doesn't use up a lot of memory so it is always open on mine.